# Wait.until returning NoSuchMethod exception using Selenium in Java AND Gradle

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle

I am having terrible time with this and I apologize in advance as I am working in Java as opposed to .NET where I am the most familiar.

I had a FluentWait in my test automation suite that was identifying a page object that was being sent as a way to wait for a page to load. A couple of days ago it all of a sudden started returning a NoSuchMethod error. This had happened before and I ungraded the google guava dependency in gradle. I upgraded my Selenium server to the latest version on seleniumhq (3.141.59) and I updated my guava dependency in my gradle build script to the latest version (27.0-jre). And I went to a WebDriverWait instead of the FluentWait. Nothing has worked so far

My test suite is set up with two projects, one with test scripts and project specific helper functions, and one core project that has basic functionality that is used across all projects that use the automation. This is where the wait functions are at

As an interesting side note, I also found that are several deprecated things within the FluentWait and WebDriverWait code such as the way that the polling interval and timeout are set. If I set the polling interval and timeout using Duration.of(xx) instead of (xx, TimeUnit.) I get an error in the top level project and execution is halted, but the core compiles with no problem. This is leading me to believe that there might be something else going on within my dependencies and this is also where my inexperience with Java and gradle doesn't help.

[image: Core Project Error]

Here is the WebDriverWait code without using the Duration

```
public static void WaitForPageLoad(WebDriver localDriver, By by)
  {
    localDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(localDriver, 30);
    wait.pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    Function<WebDriver, Boolean> objPes = new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>()
    {
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver localDriver)
      {
        return localDriver.findElement(by).isEnabled();
      }
    };
    wait.until(objPes);
    localDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Sleep(500);
  }
```

Here are my import statements

```
dependencies {

compile('com.ameritas.webcoe.testing:testing-core:1.0.62-SNAPSHOT')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
compile('com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18')
testCompile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
testCompile 'org.json:json:20170516'
testCompile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.16'
testCompile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.16'
testCompile 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.2.2.jre8'
testCompile 'io.rest-assured:json-path:3.0.7'
testCompile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.7.1'
testCompile 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:${seleniumVersion}"
testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:${seleniumVersion}"
testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:${seleniumVersion}"
drivers.each { driver ->
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-${driver}-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
}
```

}

And, finally, here is the stacktrace of the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;

at com.ameritas.webcoe.testing.common.WaitOps.WaitForPageLoad(WaitOps.java:59)
at com.ameritas.webcoe.scripts.testing.frontend.pw.pageobjects.login.LoginPage.<init>(LoginPage.java:29)
at com.ameritas.webcoe.scripts.testing.frontend.pw.scripts.PW_Frontend_SmokeTest.accountRecoveryFlowSmokeTest(PW_Frontend_SmokeTest.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:205)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:175)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:217)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:641)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Comment: Changing the wait type in the FluentWait block of code did not fix the issue. I had already tried that to no avail. I would have appreciated if someone would have asked me this before marking the question as a duplicate without so much as  a question to me as to what I had already tried

So in case someone else runs into this problem, here is the solution I came up with

But I did fix this issue in the following way. Instead of using the FluentWait and trying to identify one object on the page I changed up my page classes

Comment: When the page class loads, I am having it construct a list of expected objects in the following way

'code'
  @FindAll({
          @FindBy(name = "pageObjectName")
          @FindBy(css = "pageObjectCssSelector")
      })
  List<WebElement> objList;

I then pass this list of objects into the WaitForPageLoad function and call ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(objList)

This gives me a more secure page load than just using the FluentWait and I am convinced this is the better way to go